# Yet more consonant sameness

Tags: wordplay, language, anagram

Never one to revile the practice of doing the same idea as everyone else here is another consonant puzzle
Consonants remain in same order and the vowels shuffle so for example Lone Star State Cabs is Texas Taxis... or desperate smell is Dire Odour

Good...Hop on board the bandwagon

1.Gum up

2.Catty tart

3.Uninspiring fair

4.Fruit folk

5.Bound up bear

6.Miss Scottish island

7.Mediterranean island charm

8.Quebecois dish selection

9.Very small King Edward

10.Extra little plant

11.Quiet time-praise be!

12.Uncover pasta dish

13.Curry dish destroyer

14.Salad garnish with royal dressing

15.Deep South goodbyes

And some more difficult ones..

A.Irish comic in Michigan city

B.Light Pacific Islands rice dish

C.Middle Eastern country croquet game

D.Guam's Island Chain Soldiers

E.Australasia Rowboat Idol

And as a bonus(using an apostrophe)...What Harry Potter liked to give when he felt horny...

Comment: It's not the answer to the bonus, but it'd be a good one nonetheless: ROT13(Gur Fbeprebe'f Obar)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: So far we are missing 6,14,B and C. All the others have now received correct answers. *and the bonus... which should be Weasily solved..

Answer (score 9):

Attempted answers (combining those from NetJohn, TwoBitOperation and Mick O'Hea in other answers)

1. Gum Up

> Resin Risen

2. Catty tart

> Feline Flan (credit to Mick O'Hea) (originally: Petty patty)

3. Uninspiring Fair

> Bland Blonde (credit to NetJohn)

4. Fruit folk

> Apple People (credit to NetJohn)

5. Bound up bear

> Tied Ted

6. Miss Scottish island

> Beat Bute?

7. Mediterranean island charm

> Malta Amulet (credit to TwoBitOperation)

8. Quebecois dish selection

> Poutine Option

9. Very small King Edward

> Petite Potato

10. Extra little plant

> Bonus Bonsai (credit to TwoBitOperation)

11. Quiet time-praise be!

> Lull Alleluia

12. Uncover pasta dish

> Reveal Ravioli

13. Curry dish destroyer

> Vindaloo Vandal

14. Salad garnish with royal dressing

> Brunoise Baronies?

15. Deep South goodbyes

> Dixie Adieux

A. Irish comic in Michigan city

> Dara O'Briain Dearborn

B. Light Pacific Islands rice dish

> Lamp Lumpia

C. Middle Eastern country croquet game

> Gulf golf

D. Guam's Island Chain Soldiers

> Mariana Marine

E. Australasia Rowboat Idol

> Oceania Canoe Icon

Comment: Catty tart could also be be "feline flan".

Comment: Yes, I notice Mick O'Hea has that answer, probably works a lot better really.

Answer (score 5):

Partials:

3. Uninspiring fair

   > Bland Blonde
4. Fruit folk

   > Apple People

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

2.Catty tart

> Feline Flan

6. Miss Scottish Island

   > Sky Skye ?

Answer (score 3):

Two More:

7.Mediterranean island charm

> Malta Amulet

10.Extra little plant

> Bonus Bonsai

Comment: Yes, nice answers.

Answer (score 2):

C.Middle Eastern country croquet game

> [Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq) [Roque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roque)